# Error: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: context' ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to access `_context` from the dependency injection, however I am getting error message:

> 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: context'

I have the following in `AdminController.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GuildCars.UI.Controllers
{
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        public AdminController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public AdminController() { }    
...

public ActionResult EditUser(string id)
        {
            var userMgr = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(_context)); //fail to get _context.
            var appUser = userMgr.FindById(id);
            //var appUser = userMgr.FindByEmail(email);

            var user = new UserEditViewModel
            {
                UserID = appUser.Id,
                FirstName = appUser.FirstName,
                LastName = appUser.LastName,
                Email = appUser.Email,
                Role = appUser.Role
            };


            return View(user);
        }
```

The dependecy injection as I have above does not work, however if I use the following code it works with a using statement:

```
using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext())
                    {
                        ctx.Cars.Add(model.Car);

                        if (model.Car == null)
                            model.Car = new Car();

                        ctx.SaveChanges();
                    }
```

I checked my `Startup.Auth.cs` and I do have `ApplicationDbContext.Create`:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
...
```

Also, I checked if I have `Create()` method in `IdentityModels.cs` and I do have it.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BodyStyle> BodyStyles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ContactUs> ContactUs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ExteriorColor> ExteriorColors { get; set; }
        public DbSet<InteriorColor> InteriorColors { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Make> Makes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Model> Models { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Specials> Specials { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Transmission> Transmissions { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        }


    }
```

I am kind of new to using dependency injection in ASP.NET MVC, what could be my issue?

Comment: Did you add dbcontext using the service registrar??

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, I know in ASP.NET Core you scope it in `ConfigureServices`. But this is ASP.NET MVC, I am not aware on how it works here.

Comment: dbcontext is not in `Startup.Auth.cs` if that is what you are asking. I have ApplicationDbContext.

Comment: If this is not .net core, which dependency injection library are you using? And can you please make sure `ApplicationDbContext` is being registered in your dependency injection configurations?

Comment: Ok that was the thing, I thought this `app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);` was registering my dependency injection. Is there any guide that I could use to register `ApplicationDbContext`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft introduced IServiceCollection in ASP.NET Core 1 (a.k.a ASP.NET MVC 6). It's own dependency injection library shipped with the framework.

Prior to MVC 6, in MVC 5 we can make use of external dependency injection libraries like `unity`, `autofac` or `ninject`.

Inline is an example on how to make use of unity ioc container in ASP.NET MVC 5

- Install *'Unity'* Nuget package to your project.
- Add in your custom types to the container.
- Provide an implementation for IDependencyResolver interface with the unity container object and assign it to DependencyResolver of HttpConfiguration object.

  ```
   public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
   {
       var config = new HttpConfiguration();

       var unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
       unityContainer.RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext>();
       config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(unityContainer);

       //More code

       app.UseWebApi(config);
   }

   public class UnityResolver : IDependencyResolver
   {
       protected IUnityContainer container;

       public UnityResolver(IUnityContainer container)
       {
           if (container == null)
           {
               throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
           }
           this.container = container;
       }

       public object GetService(Type serviceType)
       {
           try
           {
               return container.Resolve(serviceType);
           }
           catch (ResolutionFailedException)
           {
               return null;
           }
       }

       public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
       {
           try
           {
               return container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
           }
           catch (ResolutionFailedException)
           {
               return new List<object>();
           }
       }

       public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
       {
           var child = container.CreateChildContainer();
           return new UnityResolver(child);
       }

       public void Dispose()
       {
           Dispose(true);
       }

       protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
       {
           container.Dispose();
       }
   }
  ```

With Unity container in place you can get rid of `app.CreatePerOwinContext` and the `create` method.